# Finding the polynomial of least degree with leading coefficient 1, integer coefficients and multiples of 100 as values

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am looking for a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients, where the leading coefficient is 1, and $100|f(x)$ for all integer $x$. I am interested in the polynomial of the lowest possible degree that meets this criterion.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- I have reformulated it as finding a polynomial $f(x)$ such that the number of solutions to the congruence $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$ is 100. This requires considering the cases of $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$ and $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ separately.

For the modulo 4 case, I have enumerated polynomials and found that the polynomial of least degree is a quartic polynomial ($x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x$),  which satisfies the condition with 4 solutions modulo 4.

However, I am unsure how to approach the modulo 25 case. I guess the answer is 25, but I can't prove it. I am looking for guidance on how to construct a polynomial of minimal degree that has 25 solutions modulo 25, or any strategies that might help in tackling this part of the problem.

Comment: Hensel's lemma?

Comment: Since [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) gives that $\varphi(25)=(5-1)\times 5=20$, then $25\mid x^{20}-1$ for all $x$ where $5\nmid x$. For the integral multiples of $5$, multiplying by $x^2$ would handle that, so $f(x)=x^2(x^{20}-1)=x^{22}-x^{2}$ works. Thus, although this is fairly likely not the most minimal degree, it does show that the lowest degree is at most $22$. Similarly for the mod $4$ case, we have that $f(x)=x^2(x^2-1)=x^4-x^2$ is an alternate degree $4$ polynomial which works.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of differences? If yes, use it to show that $100 \mid d!$, and hence $d \geq 10$. Conversely, find such a polynomial (which should be almost obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence of polynomials $f_1(x)=x(x+1), f_2(x)=x(x+1)(x+2), f_3(x)=x(x+1)(x+3)$ etc.
That is, the $n$-th polynomial $f_n(x)$ is a product with the last term being $x+n$.
It is easy to check that for any positive integer value of $x$, this product polynomial is divisibe by $n!$

(In fact for any $m$ when $f_n(m)$ is divided by $n!$ we get a binomial coefficient).

When $n$ is large enough n! can be chosen to be a multiple of 100. This idea works not only for 100,  but also  any positive integer.
But I am not sure this is the least degree polynomial with such property.

For a different approach, one can try a polynomial always divisible by 10, and then take the square of that polynomial

Comment: FYI, using your "different approach", note that $f(x)=x(x^4-1)$ is divisible by $10$ for all integers $x$. Thus, $f(x)=(x^5-x)^2=x^{10}-2x^{6}+x^2$ is always divisible by $100$. This means that a maximum value of the minimum degree is $10$. Also, regarding your idea of the sequence of polynomials, using something like Euler's totient function, along with some extra degree polynomial to handle the values which are not coprime, should reduce the maximum degree to be considerably less than the value being checked, e.g., $100$ in this case.

Comment: FYI, again, using the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) would often give a smaller value than Euler's totient function for the exponent. For example, with the case of $100$, we have that $\lambda(100)=\operatorname{lcm}(\lambda(2^2),\lambda(5^2))=\operatorname{lcm}(2,20)=20$, i.e., half of $\varphi(100)=40$.

Comment: To complete the "least degree polynomial" part, show that $100 \mid d!$ using the method of differences.

Comment: What is the method of differences @CalvinLin

Comment: See [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/#:~:text=The%20method%20of%20finite%20differences,it%20follows%20a%20polynomial%20form.). Since $f(n)$ is a multiple of 100, hence every subsequent difference is a multiple of 100. So $ 100 \mid D_d(1) = d! \times $ leading coefficient (which is 1).